# How do I explain the relationship between these two entities?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two entities, Class and Student_Class. Below are the entities:

```
Class:

ClassId (PK)         int (5)
ClassDay              varchar(9)
ClassTime            time
ModuleId (FK)    varchar(10)
TeacherId (FK)    varchar(4)

Student_Class:

ClassId (PK)         int(5)
StudentId (PK)    varchar(6)
```

My problem is that I don't know how I explain the relationship. Is it one student_class belongs to one class and on class may have many student_classes or is it vice versa because I am not sure which is funny as I created this relationship. At first I thought it was a many to many relationship but it can't be that because Student_class goes in between the Student and Class entity.

Answer (score 2):

You need a THIRD entity - Student with a PK of StudentId.

Your Student_Class is basically a "cross-reference" table. It allows the many-to-many relationship. It should have two FOREIGN KEYS (not PK). You could add two indexes for the keys if you like.

That way, each Student can have as many links to Classes as you want. You could then select a list of classes a student has, or all of the students in a given class.

Comment: Hi, Thank you I do have a student entity with a studentId linking to student class but I didn't know if it was neccessary for this question. Thank you for the answer though

Comment: FYI, it's called an *association* table. Extra columns on such rows (eg "dropped_out boolean") is called *associative data*.